# Problema na Validação com Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Oi Bom tenho que fazer um código que faça a validação de um Formulário e fiz o meu código todo e quando fui ver as validações não entraram tentei procura erros e formas de resolver e eu mesmo não conseguir achar. Alguém poderia me ajuda a fazer essas validações funciona?

Código

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" ></script>
  <TITLE>Jquery</TITLE>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
         alert('seja bem vindo');
         
   $("#formulario").validate({
       rules:{
           nome:{
               required: true,
               minlength: 2
                },

           data:{
               required: true
                },

            endereco:{
                required: true
                     },

            bairro:{
            required: true
                   },

            cidade:{
            required: true
                   },

             estado:{
             required: true
                    },

             email:{
             required: true,
             email: true
                   },

             telefone:{
             required: true
                      },

             login:{
             required: true,
             minlength: 6
                     },

             senha:{
             required: true,
             minlength: 8
                   },

             1senha:{
             required: true,
             minlength: 8
                   },
            },
            messages:{
               nome:{
                required: "Por favor, Preencha seu nome!",
                minlegth: "Seu nome tem que ter 2 Letras ou mais!"
                },

               data:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe sua data de nascimento!"
                },

                endereco:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe seu Endereço!"
                },

                bairro:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe seu Bairro!"
                },

                cidade:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe sua Cidade!"
                },

                estado:{
                required: "Por favor, Não deixe de Informar seu Estado!"
                },

                email:{
                required: "Por favor, Preencha seu email!",
                email: "E-mail inválido"
                },

                telefone:{
                required: "Por favor, digite seu telefone!"
                },

                login:{
                required: "Por favor, Escolhar um Login!",
                minlength: "Seu login deve ter 6 ou mais digitos"
                },

                senha:{
                required: "Por favor, Escolhar uma Senha!",
                minlength: "Sua senha deve ter 8 ou mais digitos"
                },

                1senha:{
                required: "Por favor, Escolhar uma Senha!",
                minlength:" Sua confirmação de Senha deve ser igual a Senha"
                },
              }
            });
          });
                
 </script>
 
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <form action="jquery.php" method="post" id="formulario">
  <table id="formulario" border='5' align='center'>
      <thead>
      <th colspan='2'>Cadastro do Usuario</th>
      <th><script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
now = new Date
document.write (""+now.getDate()+"/"+now.getMonth()+"/"+now.getFullYear () + "<br>")
document.write (now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes(0) + ":" + now.getSeconds())
</script></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td> Informe Seus Dados: </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> Nome: </td>
               <td><input type="text" name='nome'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> Data de Nascimento: </td>
               <td><input type="text"  name='data'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> Endereço: </td>
               <td><input type="text"  name='endereco'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Bairro: </td>
               <td><input type="text"  name='bairro'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>  Cidade: </td>
                <td><input type="text"  name='cidade'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> Estado: </td>
               <td>
               <select name="estado">
               <option>Selecione...</option>
               <option>Acre (AC)</option>
               <option>Alagoas (AL)</option>
               <option>Amapá (AP)</option>
               <option>Amazonas (AM)</option>
               <option>Bahia (BA)</option>
               <option>Ceará (CE)</option>
               <option>Distrito Federal (DF)</option>
               <option>Espírito Santo (ES)</option>
               <option>Goiás (GO)</option>
               <option>Maranhão (MA)</option>
               <option>Mato Grosso (MT)</option>
               <option>Mato Grosso do Sul (MS)</option>
               <option>Minas Gerais (MG)</option>
               <option>Pará (PA)</option>
               <option>Paraíba (PB)</option>
               <option>Paraná (PR)</option>
               <option>Pernambuco (PE)</option>
               <option>Piauí (PI)</option>
               <option>Rio de Janeiro (RJ)</option>
               <option>Rio Grande do Norte (RN)</option>
               <option>Rio Grande do Sul (RS)</option>
               <option>Rondônia (RO)</option>
               <option>Roraima (RR)</option>
               <option>Santa Catarina (SC)</option>
               <option>São Paulo (SP)</option>
               <option>Sergipe (SE)</option>
               <option>Tocantins (TO)</option>
                 </select></td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> E-mail: </td>
              <td><input type="text"  name='email'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Telefone Celular: </td>
              <td><input type="text"  name='telefone'/> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> Login: </td>
             <td><input type="text"  name='login'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Senha: </td>
            <td><input type="text"  name='senha'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Confirme a Senha: </td>
             <td><input type="text"  name='1senha'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan='2' align='center'><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="botão"/></td>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
       <th colspan='3'> Envie seu Formulario </th>
       </tfoot>
  
  </table>
  </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Pergunta, porque voce nao usa o atributo required do input HTML5?? `<input type="text" required>` por exemplo?

Comment: Me desculpe mas ainda sou iniciante nessa Area e meu professor não chegou a essa parte. Poderia me falar mais sobre ??

Comment: Voce tem tags `<input>` no seu HTML certo? Se a unica validacao que voce precisa eh que eles estejam preenchidos (sao obrigatorios), basta voce adicionar eles como voce ja esta fazendo, e no final antes da tag de final `>` colocar `required`, tipo assim: `<input required>`. Dai o proprio navegador valida pra voce e precisa de bem menos codigo jQuery ;)

Comment: Ah entendi Obrigado. Porem eu também quero que apareça uma mensagem quando deixarem em branco o espaço. eu posso acrescenta essa mensagem no próprio input ?

Comment: 1senha:{   começando por número, pode isso Arnaldo? só estou perguntando

Comment: Você pode acrescentar < input type="text"  name='email' required title="Este campo não pode ficar em branco zé.">

Comment: entendi vou tenta então. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: leofontes e Leo Caracciolo muito obrigado pela ajuda de vocês deu certo o código aqui. Meu erro estava apenas na palavra "1senha" não me lembrava que não podia começa com numero os names.

Comment: mas se vocês podesse me ajuda só mais uma vez. como faço para a aparecer um aviso quando a confirmação da Senha for diferente da Senha usando Jquery validation ???

Answer (score 0):

Substitua no seu HTML as linhas senha e confirma senha por estas que tem id para verificação se são iguais.

Fiz uma alteração no name da confirma senha porque não pode começar com numero (1senha).

```
<td><input type="text" id="senha" name='senha'/> </td>

<td><input type="text" id="conf_senha" name='conf_senha'/> </td>
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('seja bem vindo');
        $('#formulario').validate({
            rules:{
                nome:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                data:{
                 required: true
                },
                endereco:{
                 required: true
                },
                bairro:{
              required: true
                },

             cidade:{
              required: true
                },

              estado:{
               required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                telefone:{
               required: true
                },
              login:{
               required: true,
              minlength: 6
                },
              senha:{
               required: true,
               minlength: 8

                },
              conf_senha:{
               required: true,
               minlength: 8,
               equalTo: "#senha"
              }

            },
            messages:{
                nome:{
                required: "Por favor, Preencha seu nome!",
                minlegth: "Seu nome tem que ter 2 Letras ou mais!"
                },

               data:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe sua data de nascimento!"
                },

                endereco:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe seu Endereço!"
                },

                bairro:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe seu Bairro!"
                },

                cidade:{
                required: "Por favor, Informe sua Cidade!"
                },

                estado:{
                required: "Por favor, Não deixe de Informar seu Estado!"
                },

                email:{
                required: "Por favor, Preencha seu email!",
                email: "E-mail inválido"
                },

                telefone:{
                required: "Por favor, digite seu telefone!"
                },

                login:{
                required: "Por favor, Escolhar um Login!",
                minlength: "Seu login deve ter 6 ou mais digitos"
                },

                senha:{
                required: "Por favor, Escolha uma Senha!",
                minlength: "Sua senha deve ter 8 ou mais digitos"
                },
                conf_senha:{
                required: "Por favor, Escolha uma Senha!",
                minlength:" Sua confirmação de Senha deve ser igual a Senha",
                equalTo: "Sua confirmação de Senha deve ser igual a Senha"

                }
            }
             
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>


<form action="jquery.php" method="post" id="formulario">
  <table id="formulario" border='5' align='center'>
      <thead>
      <th colspan='2'>Cadastro do Usuario</th>
      <<th><script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
now = new Date
document.write (""+now.getDate()+"/"+now.getMonth()+"/"+now.getFullYear () + "<br>")
document.write (now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes(0) + ":" + now.getSeconds())
</script></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td> Informe Seus Dados: </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> Nome: </td>
               <td><input type="text" name='nome'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> Data de Nascimento: </td>
               <td><input type="text"  name='data'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> Endereço: </td>
               <td><input type="text"  name='endereco'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Bairro: </td>
               <td><input type="text"  name='bairro'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>  Cidade: </td>
                <td><input type="text"  name='cidade'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> Estado: </td>
               <td>
               <select name="estado">
               <option>Selecione...</option>
               <option>Acre (AC)</option>
               <option>Alagoas (AL)</option>
               <option>Amapá (AP)</option>
               <option>Amazonas (AM)</option>
               <option>Bahia (BA)</option>
               <option>Ceará (CE)</option>
               <option>Distrito Federal (DF)</option>
               <option>Espírito Santo (ES)</option>
               <option>Goiás (GO)</option>
               <option>Maranhão (MA)</option>
               <option>Mato Grosso (MT)</option>
               <option>Mato Grosso do Sul (MS)</option>
               <option>Minas Gerais (MG)</option>
               <option>Pará (PA)</option>
               <option>Paraíba (PB)</option>
               <option>Paraná (PR)</option>
               <option>Pernambuco (PE)</option>
               <option>Piauí (PI)</option>
               <option>Rio de Janeiro (RJ)</option>
               <option>Rio Grande do Norte (RN)</option>
               <option>Rio Grande do Sul (RS)</option>
               <option>Rondônia (RO)</option>
               <option>Roraima (RR)</option>
               <option>Santa Catarina (SC)</option>
               <option>São Paulo (SP)</option>
               <option>Sergipe (SE)</option>
               <option>Tocantins (TO)</option>
                 </select></td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
       <td> E-mail: </td>
              <td><input type="text" name='email'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Telefone Celular: </td>
              <td><input type="text" name='telefone'/> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> Login: </td>
             <td><input type="text" name='login'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Senha: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="senha" name='senha'/> </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td> Confirme a Senha: </td>
             <td><input type="text" id="conf_senha" name='conf_senha'/> </td>
     </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan='2' align='center'><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="botão"/></td>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
       <th colspan='3'> Envie seu Formulario </th>
       </tfoot>
  
  </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado. me ajudou Bastante